# Activity not launching on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I am using custom dialog to add text in a bitmap. Bitmap is created when i click on the screen but after the creation of first bitmap my app crashes.
The error log is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(619): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.svtutorial/com.example.svtutorial.NodeMenu}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(619): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime(619): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.example.svtutorial.NodeMenu.onCreate(NodeMenu.java:26)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

This is my main class

```
package com.example.svtutorial;
//imports

public class SurfaceViewEx extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

DrawingView dv;
Bitmap bitmap;
Context context;
SurfaceHolder holder;
LinkedList<Node> nodes;
float x, y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cloud);
    dv = new DrawingView(this); //Passing the context of this class
    dv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x = y = 0;
    setContentView(dv);
    nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    //pointList = new ArrayList<MotionEvent.PointerCoords>();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

public class DrawingView extends SurfaceView  {

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();           
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch(me.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                Node n = new Node(bitmap, c, x, y);
                boolean collision = false;
                if (!nodes.isEmpty()){
                    for (Node no : nodes) {
                        collision = no.isHere(x, y); //Checks the touch on bitmap
                        if (collision){
                        break;
                        }
                      }
                     }
            if(!collision){
                 nodes.add(n);
                }
            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            if (!nodes.isEmpty()){
                  for (Node no : nodes) {
                         no.Draw();
                        if(collision) { //I want to call dialog box here
                      Intent text = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NodeMenu.class);
                      startActivity(text);
                  finish();
                      }
                           }
                 }
                     holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                 break;
                         }
               return true;
               }
                 }
```

The code given below is for the creation of dialog box and i want to it in the class given above.

```
public class NodeMenu extends Activity{

Context context;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.nodemenu);
    dialog.setTitle(R.id.textHeader);
    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button addTextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addText);
    addTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

Layout of node menu

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textHeader"
    android:src="@drawable/addtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/nodetext" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/addText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Text" />"

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your error log?

Comment: i have posted the error..please review it

Answer (score 0):

As the logcat tells you:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-30 02:06:38.892: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.example.svtutorial.NodeMenu.onCreate(NodeMenu.java:26)

you have a `NullPointerException` on line 26 of your `NodeMenu` class.

Comment: give me some solution of this problem..I am new in android

Comment: addTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `onCreate`  method in NodeMenu. You can see better which is line 26, the line where the problem occurs.

Here're my thoughts.

- The way you create the custom view - extension of `SurfaceView` - can not work with Android. I recommend the reading about [custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) to understand what is really necessary to link your view correctly to the Android system.
- I understand that you try to do drawings on your own. A lot of these things can be done by libraries that are already part of Android. Tested and optimized intelligent people (most of them ;-). You should first get familiar with the possibilities that are already there. My feeling is that a reading about styles in Android might bring you further.

Than, when you're really sure you have to do drawings on your own, you can go once more to the link above and read the second chapter about custom drawings.

Comment: the code on line 26 
addTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
and what are those libraries ?

Comment: The code in line 26 means, that `R.id.addText` cannot be found as view in Activities layout. Can you edit your question and post layout? The libraries around custom drawing can be found in this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Comment: I had posted the layout..please check